# Integrating PostgreSQL with EasyPHP : Database connection could not be established

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, pgadmin, easyphp

I have been building my php application using login-php framework ( https://github.com/panique/php-login), with as a dev environment EasyPHP 5.3.9, Apache 2.2.21 VC9 and MySQL 5.5.20.

Now I would like to upgrade to a PostgreSQL database, I went throught the required installation and configuration. Currently, I had created a database via phpPgAdmin 5.1 ( PostgreSQL 9.3.5 ). However after setting the PDO in my php config file and when running my application, I get a "Database connection could not be established" error.

Here is the instructions I have been following https://github.com/normai/php-login-xdb.

```
  /**
   * Configuration for: Database
   */
  define('DB_TYPE', 'pgsql');
  define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
  define('DB_PORT', '5432');
  define('DB_NAME', 'test');
  define('DB_USER', 'postgres');
  define('DB_PASS', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_FILE', '');
```

I had also uncommented the following lines in php.ini

```
  extension=php_pgsql.dll
  extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Is there anything else I missing to have the right configuration of PostgreSQL with my windows dev environment ?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes - what is the error?

Comment: All I'm getting is this message: "Database connection could not be established"

Comment: Can you check if the postgres module is loaded? From cli: `php -m` or with `phpinfo();` via http

Comment: It is loaded .. with a double check I found out that I did not update a lib file that has changed with the new version of php-login . So now my application is running well with postgreSQL. Thanks !

Comment: I am glad that I helped you to find the error! Please upvote my comment! :)